# Finding error difference row wise between two dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, difference

Is there an easier way to find the percent difference between two dataframes.

For example:

```
df1((row1,col1) -df2(row1, col1))/average(df1(row1,col1), df2(row1,col1))
```

[The picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bnid1.png) shows the original dataframes, where I do it in a more manual way.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please [edit] your question to include sample input and output, and your code in the text of the question, not as pictures. This is to provide a [mcve] in order to better understand what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: Please give samples of the two databases and a sample of expected outcome. Please also include what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the element-wise difference between two data frames like this:

```
diff_df = df1 - df2
```

The same way, you can add them together and divide them by 2. And multiply them by 100:

```
avg_df = (df1 + df2) / 2
```

You can divide `diff_df` by `avg_df` using `.div()`. Multiplying that with 100 should get you what you need:

```
diff_df / avg_df * 100
```

---

You can also use the pandas methods to do this:

```
diff_df = df1.subtract(df2)
avg_df = df1.add(df2) / 2

diff_df.div(avg_df) * 100
```

---

Or, as a one-liner:

```
df1.subtract(df2).div(df1.add(df2).div(2)).mul(100)
```